# Is it possible to group elements without closing the stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to group elements in a `Stream`, but then continue streaming instead of having to create a new stream from the `EntrySet` of the returned map?

For example, I can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // map of access date to list of users
    // Person is a POJO with first name, last name, etc.
    Map<Date, List<Person>> dateMap = new HashMap<>();
    // ...
    // output, sorted by access date, then person last name
    dateMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).forEach(e -> {
        Date date = e.getKey();
        // group persons by last name and sort
        // this part seems clunky
        e.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getLastName, Collectors.toSet()))
                .entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).forEach(e2 -> {
            // pool agent id is the key
            String lastName = e2.getKey();
            Set<Person> personSet = e2.getValue();
            float avgAge = calculateAverageAge(personSet);
            int numPersons = personSet.size();
            // write out row with date, lastName, avgAge, numPersons
        });
    });
}
```

Which works just fine, but seems a little clunky, especially the streaming into a map, and then immediately streaming on the entry set of that map.

Is there a way to group objects in a stream, but continue streaming?

Comment: the short answer is *No*; but may be you can explain exactly what you want to achieve (input and output) and we can help with that?

Comment: @Eugene Thanks. The question contains exactly what I want to achieve, more or less. I have the dateMap to work with, and I need to output rows to a report grouped by date, then last name, and ordered by either date or last name.

Comment: None of that is obvious in your question.  All that I can deduce is that you want to order the Persons by date, and then by last name.  Is that sorting sufficient, or do you really need them grouped?

Comment: VGR is right.. it's at least slightly confusing; the best way to explain it would be to provide an example here

Comment: I think I need them grouped. I added to the example - does that help?

Comment: @lucasvw that's not an example I meant... what I had in mind is: here is the Map I have (with some pseudo-real small data) and here is what List/Map/whatever I want to end-up with

Comment: I think you're overthinking what I want to do. The map has a few thousand entries, each of which has a list of anywhere from a dozen to a few hundred Person objects in the list. I need to write out a row for each distinct group of last name and date, and the output needs to be ordered by date and last name in either order. I could provided pseudo-data, but I'm not sure how that changes anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten your code by using Map.forEach, downstream collectors, TreeMap, and IntSummaryStatistics.

By grouping into a `TreeMap` (instead of leaving it up to the `groupingBy` collector), you get the names sorted automatically. Instead of immediately getting the grouped map, you add a `summarizingInt` collector that turns the list of persons with the same name into `IntSummaryStatistics` of their ages.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Date, List<Person>> dateMap = new HashMap<>();
    dateMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).forEach(e -> {
        Date date = e.getKey();

        e.getValue().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getLastName,
                                                   TreeMap::new,
                                                   Collectors.summarizingInt(Person::getAge)))
                    .forEach((name, stats) -> System.out.println(date +" "+ 
                                                                 lastName +" "+
                                                                 stats.getAverage() +" "+
                                                                 stats.getCount()));
    });
}
```

If you have control over the type of the initial map, you could use TreeMap there as well, and shorten it further:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Date, List<Person>> dateMap = new TreeMap<>();
    dateMap.forEach((date, persons -> { ...
```

Comment: I know, it’s tempting to use a `TreeMap`, to have the map already sorted after the `groupingBy` collection, but contrary to the first intuition, collecting into the default (hash) map and sorting afterwards will be more efficient in most cases.

Comment: @Holger That was my thinking. Thank you though, Malte!

Comment: @Holger thanks for pointing it out. I thought there might be a difference there, but wanted to keep the code shorter. Lucas, if that performance impact is of concern, you could still use the downstream collector to summarize the persons, and replace `forEach` with `entrySet.stream.sorted.foreach`. It almost the same as your code then, but at least the average is already calculated. Holger, do you have an idea how to get around materializing the grouped map?

Comment: Doing the `summarizingInt` during the grouping instead of creating temporary `Set`s will indeed improve the performance. Grouping into a `TreeSet` becomes interesting if you don’t use the natural order as grouping criteria, which leads to the point that the `Map` is unavoidable, as it is a crucial part of the grouping operation itself. The map logic determines the groups (via its lookup implementation) and the map provides the required intermediate storage. Since you don’t know to which group the last element belongs to, there is no way to proceed with any group before having grouped all items

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways to interpret the question, but if we restate the question as, "Is it possible to group elements within a Stream without using a *terminal operation* and apply stream operations to the resulting groups within the same stream pipeline," then the answer is "**Yes**." In this restatement of the question, *terminal operation* is defined in the way that the Java 8 streams API defines it.

Here is an example that demonstrates this.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

class StreamGrouper {

    public static class GroupableObj<K extends Comparable<? super K>, T>
            implements Comparable<GroupableObj<K, T>> {

        private K key;
        private T obj;
        private Set<T> setOfObj;

        public GroupableObj(K key, T obj) {
            if (key == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Key may not be null");
            }
            this.key = key;
            this.obj = obj;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(GroupableObj<K, T> otherGroupable) {
            return key.compareTo(otherGroupable.key);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object otherObj) {
            if (otherObj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (otherObj instanceof GroupableObj) {
                GroupableObj<?, ?> otherGroupable =
                        (GroupableObj<?, ?>)otherObj;
                return setOfObj == otherGroupable.setOfObj &&
                        key.equals(otherGroupable.key);
            }
            return false;
        }

        public Set<T> getGroup() {
            return setOfObj;
        }

        public K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public T getObject() {
            return obj;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return key.hashCode();
        }

        public void setGroup(Set<T> setOfObj) {
            this.setOfObj = setOfObj;
        }
    }

    public static class PeekGrouper<K extends Comparable<? super K>, T>
            implements Consumer<GroupableObj<K, T>> {

        private Map<K, Set<T>> groupMap;

        public PeekGrouper() {
            groupMap = new HashMap<>();
        }

        @Override
        public void accept(GroupableObj<K, T> groupable) {
            K key = groupable.getKey();
            Set<T> group = groupMap.computeIfAbsent(key,
                    (k) -> new HashSet<T>());
            groupable.setGroup(group);
            group.add(groupable.getObject());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Function<Double, Long> myKeyExtractor =
                (dblObj) -> Long.valueOf(
                (long)(Math.floor(dblObj.doubleValue()*10.0)));
        PeekGrouper<Long, Double> myGrouper = new PeekGrouper<>();

        Random simpleRand = new Random(20190527L);
        simpleRand.doubles(100).boxed().map((dblObj) ->
                new GroupableObj<Long, Double>(
                myKeyExtractor.apply(dblObj), dblObj)).peek(myGrouper).
                distinct().sorted().
                map(GroupableObj<Long, Double>::getGroup).
                forEachOrdered((grp) -> System.out.println(grp));
    }
}
```

In order to make a program that can be compiled and executed on its own, this example moves away from using the `Person` objects that are referenced in the question, but the grouping concept is the same, and the code from the question could turn into something like the following.

```
PeekGrouper<String, Person> myGrouper = new PeekGrouper<>();
e.getValue().stream().map((p) -> new GroupableObj<String, Person>(
        p.getLastName(), p)).peek(myGrouper).distinct().sorted().
        forEachOrdered(e2 -> {
    String lastName = e2.getKey();
    Set<Person> personSet = e2.getGroup();
    float avgAge = calculateAverageAge(personSet);
    int numPersons = personSet.size();
    // write out row with date, lastName, avgAge, numPersons
});
```

Please note that in order for this example to work, it is required that the stream call both the `distinct` function (which reduces the stream to only a single instance of each group) and the `sorted` function (which ensures that the entire stream has been processed and the groups have been fully "collected" before processing continues). Also note that as implemented here `GroupableObj` is not safe to use with parallel streams.  If the terminal operation of the stream does not require that the groups be fully "collected" when it processes the objects -- for example, if the terminal operation were something like `Collectors.toList()` -- then a call to `sorted` would not be required.  The critical point is that any portion of the stream that sees the groups prior to a call to `sorted` and prior to the end of a terminal operation (including processing during a terminal operation) may see a group that is incomplete.

For the specific example in the question, it may be somewhat less time-efficient to sort the objects before grouping them if many of them are in the same group, but if you are willing to sort the objects before grouping them, you can achieve the same functionality without performing any streaming after doing the grouping.  The following is a rewrite of the first example from this answer that demonstrates this.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collector;

class PreSortOrderedGrouper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Function<Double, Long> myKeyExtractor =
                (dblObj) -> Long.valueOf(
                (long)(Math.floor(dblObj.doubleValue()*10.0)));
        Random simpleRand = new Random(20190527L);
        Consumer<Set<Double>> groupProcessor =
                (grp) -> System.out.println(grp);
        simpleRand.doubles(100).boxed().sorted(
                Comparator.comparing(myKeyExtractor)).
                collect(Collector.of(HashSet<Double>::new,
                (set, dblObj) -> {
                    if (set.isEmpty() || myKeyExtractor.apply(set.iterator().
                            next()) == myKeyExtractor.apply(dblObj)) {
                        set.add(dblObj);
                    } else {
                        groupProcessor.accept(set);
                        set.clear();
                        set.add(dblObj);
                    }
                },
                (setOne, setTwo) -> {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                },
                (finalSet) -> {
                    groupProcessor.accept(finalSet);
                    return Integer.valueOf(0);
                }));
    }
}
```

I can't be sure that either of these examples will feel less "clunky" to you, but if the example in your question is a pattern you use frequently, you could probably adapt one or both of these examples in ways that will suit your purposes and, aside from a few utility classes, result in no more code than you are currently using.